# jQuery not working for inclusion of html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, include, jframe

```
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
<script src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script>
$(function(){
$("#includedContent").load("b.html");
});
</script>

</head>


<body>
<div id="includedContent"></div>
</body>
```

Why is it not working? Apparently I have to type some nonsense to satisfy the right-wing robot on this site.

Comment: Why do you have jQuery included twice (if indeed the second one is a jquery library)?

Comment: Why are you including 2 jQuery libraries?

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: What debugging have you done? Checked the javascript console? Checked the network tab for the request and response?

Comment: Have you tried fully qualifying b.html?

Comment: What is the error in the console?

Comment: "Failed to load resource: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. file:///Users/harry/Desktop/HARRY%20TO%20SORT/Archive/b.html
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/harry/Desktop/HARRY%20TO%20SORT/Archive/b.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. template.html:1"

Comment: What I am I doing to cause this error??

Comment: @THarryEvans The issue is that you are using the `file://` protocol to load your webpage, which can cause issues with ajax calls. I would recommend avoiding the issue by installing a web server, like Apache or IIS Express.

Comment: Thank you :) I will try that and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: YEESSSS thank you!!! it works!!! I am using a Macintosh, so Apache is pre-installed. All i had to do was enable it from System Preferences and then move my web-folder to the sites folder in the home directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code, other than including the jQuery library multiple times, seems fine; I suspect the issue has to do with the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header.

How are you testing this page? If you are testing locally and the server is not supporting CORS, the script would be unable to load b.html.  To check, in the JavaScript console you should see messages about Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is not present.

Comment: If `b.html` is the actual URL, then there wouldn't be a cross-domain issue since it would be loaded from the same domain that the page was loaded from. But maybe that's not the actual url.

Comment: @cookiemonster This could be it, if he is loading his page with the `file://` protocol. Can't tell for sure, but this is the most likely answer so far.

Comment: @JasonP: Good point. Some browsers have issue with that.

Comment: "Failed to load resource: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. file:///Users/harry/Desktop/HARRY%20TO%20SORT/Archive/b.html XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/harry/Desktop/HARRY%20TO%20SORT/Archive/b.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. template.html:1"

Comment: @cookiemonster i think it's in the same domain. as in i have a folder called "Archive" in which my template.html & b.html are located.

Comment: @THarryEvans: Some browsers seem to see any access using `file://` as cross-domain. It's much easier if you have a local web server to host the site.

Comment: Yep! You were right. SOLVED!!! Thank you ever so much for the help guys :)